# print as HEX (0x) or Decimal depending on value without if statements - how to?

Tags: c, macros, hex, printf, format-specifiers

I am trying to print an integer and its formatting should be %d decimal unless its of value FFFF in which case it should be printed as 0xFFFF. I am unable to do so without unnecessary if and else statements. Would it be possible to do this in a single printf statement? Maybe use a macro? Any pointers?

```
int d;

if(d==0xFFFF) {
    printf("%X",d);
} else {
    printf("%d",d);
}
```

Comment: One way or another you'll need an if statement because you don't know the value of d at compile time. You could use the terniary operator, but its still a branch.

Comment: "without unnecessary if and else" Then maybe they are not unnecessary. What do you expect to gain by replacing an `if else` with some obfuscated code?

Comment: Maybe something like `printf(d == 0xffff ? "%X" : "%d", d)` ?

Comment: Neither portable nor necessarily fast, but at least branch free: `printf((char[]){'%', 'd'+!(d%0xFFFF)*20, 0}, d);`. And yeah it's probably a bad idea to write code like that.

Comment: Note: with 16-bit `int`, `d==0xFFFF` is true when `d == -1`, even though `0xFFFF` is a positive value.

Comment: Surely "unwanted" rather than "unnecessary" if?

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
int main(void) {

    for( int e = 0xFFFE; e < 0x10002; e++ )
        printf( "%d\n\0%X\n" + ((e == 0xFFFF)<<2), e );

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
65534
FFFF
65536
65537
```

You'll recognise the conditional testing the value of the variable. The truth value (0 or 1) is shifted left 2 places, effectively multiplying it by 4. This value (0 or 4) is added to the address of the *hacky and custom* format string that is actually two C strings in one. Either `"%d\n\0"` or `"%X\n\0"` will be used by `printf()` to print the next parameter.

Now, go read the man page for `printf()` and work out how to print the hex value with a leading `0x`. (Hint: changing `"..\0%X.."` to `"..\00X%x.."` will NOT work. Why not?)

Don't write code like this. It's definitely a hack...

Comment: Hmm, `e < 0x10002` is always true with 16-bit `int`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If such a constraint formed part of the task, I'm _certain_ the OP would have specified the datatype to be `short`... `:-)`

Comment: "(Hint: changing "..\0%X.." to "..\00X%x.." will NOT work. Why not?)" Works for me.

Comment: @Joshua Then either you're accepting "Xffff" as a legitimate hexadecimal notation, or your compiler is broken...

Comment: @Fe2O3: `int main() { printf("0x%X\n", 0xFFFF); }` produces output `0xFFFF`.

Comment: @Fe2O3: Oh I see. It only fails because of the preceding escape code. Tons of ways to fix that and most of them aren't in the printf manual.

Comment: @Joshua The answers are out there. To find them, one must only learn to read between the lines...

Comment: @Fe2O3: Fun fact: C has a zero length operator.

Comment: @Joshua I've no idea what you're referring to. On topic here is fulfilling the OP's objective without using `if/else` (or its cousin, the conditional expression.) I can think of two simple solutions (not "tons") to obtain the desired "0x" herald. If you've something useful to contribute, please do.

Comment: @Fe2O3: `printf("Hello, " "World");`

Comment: @Joshua Congratulations. That's one solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid the `if` statement with the conditional operator to select the `printf` statement:

```
    d == 0xFFFF ? printf("FFFF") : printf("%d", d);
```

You can combine this into a single call to `printf`:

```
    printf(d == 0xFFFF ? "FFFF" : "%d", d);
```

You can avoid the conditional operator and make the code even more cryptic:

```
    printf("FFFF\0%d" + (d != 0xFFFF) * 5, d);
```